# Java: gerar o desenho de um autômato finito não-determinístico (AFND)

Tags: java, biblioteca

Eu estou fazendo um programinha que recebe um arquivo de texto com parametros de um automato não determinístico, a partir dele são criadas regras para esse automato, com ifs para onde deverá ir cada estado. Entanto no fim deverei montar um automato e printar toda a árvore dele. Como poderia fazer essa parte desde print? alguma ideia de que pelo que buscar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa encontrei essa biblioteca em java que auxilia no print do automato:

https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

Comment: Se puder se delongar um pouco mais na resposta (nem que seja com um grafo mockado e a respectiva imagem gerada) eu agradeço muito.